How would I duplicate QGraphicsItem's in one function?
How would I duplicate selected items on the scene (self.canvas)?
def use_duplicate(self):
    self.label_btn.setChecked(False)
    self.path_btn.setChecked(False)

    items = self.canvas.selectedItems()
    self.duplicate_stack.append(items)

    for item in items:
        try:
            items = self.duplicate_stack.pop()

            print(self.duplicate_stack)

            self.canvas.addItem(items)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


I tried using a list and then grabbing items from the list and adding them to my scene, but this doesn't work. I am curious why there isn't a .clone() method or something along those lines.
Any help is appreciated.

There is no clone() function because the standard items are just considered as extendible primitives, so it's better to leave that task to the programmer, instead of implementing a function that would certainly be overridden anyway. Iterate through all selected items, use isinstance(item, <graphics item class>) and eventually create a similar one by also copying its main properties, such as its coordinates/geometry, pen and brush for shape items, etc.

I solved this by copying an item's attributes and creating a new version of itself (QGraphicsTextItem for example):
    def duplicate(self):
        item = CustomTextItem()
        item.setFont(self.font())
        item.setDefaultTextColor(self.defaultTextColor())
        item.setPlainText(self.toPlainText())
        item.setPos(self.pos())
        item.setScale(self.scale())
        item.setRotation(self.rotation())
        item.setZValue(self.zValue())
        item.setTransform(self.transform())
        item.setTransformOriginPoint(self.transformOriginPoint())

        item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        item.setToolTip('Text')

        self.scene().addItem(item)

        return item

